# QSql module and multithreaded application

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qtsql

I'm troubled by how the Sql module works with multithreaded application in Qt.
        http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/threads-modules.html#threads-and-the-sql-module clearly states
        that "A connection can only be used from within the thread that created it".

However this piece of code I wrote works :

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QSqlQuery>
#include <QtConcurrentRun>

void    req()
{
  QSqlQuery q("INSERT INTO users (username) VALUES (\"test\")");
}

void    db()
{
  QSqlDatabase _db;

  _db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL");
  _db.setDatabaseName("dbname");
  _db.setHostName("host");
  _db.setUserName("username");
  _db.setPassword("password");
  if (_db.open())
    std::cout << "Ok" << std::endl;
  else
    std::cout << "Error" << std::endl;
}

int     main(int ac, char **av)
{
  QCoreApplication app(ac, av);
  QtConcurrent::run(db);
  sleep(1);
  QtConcurrent::run(req);
  return app.exec();
}
```

My application design requires multiple threads to interact with a database. Thoses threads 
are spawned and managed by QtConcurrent::run().

So, since this piece of code works should I go for it or will I run into
troubles doing that ?

Any help, documentation or explanation is welcome !
Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The above code is fine because QSqlQuery [creates its *own* QSqlDatabase](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqlquery.html#QSqlQuery-2). It would be a problem if it referenced `_db` as created by `db()`. The down side is that it doesn't actually *do* anything.

QSqlDatabase is not a QObject but it has-a [driver](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqldatabase.html#driver) which is a QObject and therefore has [thread affinity](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/thread-basics.html#qobject-and-threads).

If creating loads of QSqlDatabases is prohibitive, create [worker threads](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_pool_pattern) which maintains their own connection. Then dispatch queries to these threads rather than creating new threads and therefore new connections.

Comment: What do you mean by "The down side is that it doesn't actually do anything." ? My query is executed, and the entry inserted. If I understand decently, QSqlQuery will create its own QSqlDatabase using the database configuration from the db created by `QSqlDatabase::addDatabase()` ? Does that imply a lot of overhead (because of objects' copies or something)?

Comment: Your `QSqlQuery` object knows nothing about the `QSqlDatabase` you also created because you're _not_ using the "`db` connected" constructor `QSqlQuery::QSqlQuery(QString&, QSqlDatabase)` (i.e. you don't pass the pre-created `db` to the query). The way you instantiate the query means that a new, separate DB connection will be created/torn down each time `req()` is called. Which is thread-safe, but potentially expensive.

Comment: I did some more testing, and calling multiple QtConcurent::run(req) is causing the test program to segfault. edit: it seems that the query instanciation is not thread safe.

Comment: I'd guess that's because although many Qt method calls are reentrant, they're not always thread-safe, and the global database object is getting screwed-up. Create one QSqlDatabase per worker thread with its own connection, and create all queries in that thread from that database.